# Distributing $n$ people into $m$ groups

Tags: combinatorics

For example if we have 22 people and we want to distribute them into two groups there are $\binom{22}{11}/2$ possibilities.

But I'm wondering, can we generalise this if we say how many possibilities are there to distribute $n$ people into $m$ equally large groups? (Even more difficult, what if each group is of a different size?)

And how does importance of order and if order in the groups doesn't matter, affect the end result?

Comment: We have the multinomial coefficient

Comment: May be this (Wolfram Mathword page on partition function) can be helpful to you https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html

Comment: Are you assuming the number of groups divides the amount of people?

Answer (score 1):

- While dividing people into groups, you need to take into account whether the groups are labeled or unlabeled Your example of $\binom{22}{11}/2$ applies only to unlabeled groups. Had the groups been labeled, say Tigers and Lions, the answer would have been just $\binom{22}{11}$
- It is obvious you can generalise for more groups of equal size. For $3$ unlabeled groups of $5$ from $15$ people. for example, you would get $\binom{15}5\binom{10}5\binom55 \div 3!$
- If group sizes or composition (say, men/women) vary, the groups automatically become labeled, so if we divided the previous $15$ into groups of size $8,4,3$ the answer would just  be $\binom{15}8\binom74\binom33$
- Finally, if order *within* groups mattered, in the previous example, you would need to multiply by $8!4!3!$ Or what would be much simpler, just permute all (so $15!$) and draw dividing lines after $8$ and $12$ people.

Comment: What if I have three groups and 10 people but Group 1 consists of 3 Group 2 also of 3 but group 3 of 4 people? Would the answer then be $\binom{10}{4}\binom{10}{3}/2$?

Comment: @bochner.martinelli: If you mean $\binom{10}4\binom63 /2$, then yes.

Comment: Almost certainly this is a duplicate?